# Adding a space between variables

Tags: ruby, string

I made a program. The names that are displayed are not separated by a space. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

```
puts 'hello there, what is your forename?'
forename = gets.chomp
puts 'your middlename?'
middlename = gets.chomp
puts 'and your last name?'
surname = gets.chomp
puts 'so your full name is, ' + forename + middlename + surname + '. '
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gets.chomp` method itself does not catch any spaces. You will have to add them yourself.

Another Ruby way how to do that is through the `join` method.

```
puts "So your full name is, #{[forename, middlename, surname].join(' ')}."
```

With David's suggestion to form a complete answer, use `compact` before the joining, in order to avoid empty middlename and doubling of space.

```
puts "So your full name is, #{[forename, middlename, surname].compact.join(' ')}."
```

Comment: If you put a .compact on that array of names then it will handle a nil name element very neatly.

Answer (score 3):

There are no spaces, because you are not printing them anywhere. You can interpolate variables (mind `"` double quotes):

```
puts "so your full name is,  #{forename} #{middlename} #{surname}."
```

Or explicitly concatenate with spaces  `' '`:

```
puts 'so your full name is, ' + forename + ' ' +  middlename + ' ' + surname + '. '
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Ruby person (to be honest I have no idea about Ruby), but you could try this

```
puts 'so your full name is, ' + forename + ' ' + middlename + ' ' + surname + '. '
```